# jsTree trigger select_node function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have got jsTree and a button. jsTree has select_node function

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
 // some code
})
```

is it possible to trigger select_node event on button click?

Answer (score 0):

The way to use anything you `bind`ed in jQuery is done via `trigger` (or `triggerHandler`).

```
.trigger('select_node.jstree', data)
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: what should I put instead of "data" ? $('#tree').jstree('get_selected') doesn`t work for me.

Comment: this `data` is slightly the same than the once from your question actually.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a

```
function onSelectNode(selectedNode) {/* do stuff */}
```

and then you can call it in your event bind like this

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {
    onSelectNode(data.node);
})
```

and then instead of trying to trigger 'select_node' yourself you can just call

```
onSelect(treeInstance.get_selected(true)[0])
```

note: you must have already saved the reference of tree in a variable in global scope to access it later

```
treeInstance = $('#div').jstree(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the select_node.jstree using trigger i.e

```
.trigger('select_node.jstree', data)
```

where data is complete node that you need to select